# Django objects.filter in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have django project with three below models:

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Album(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='album_logos', default='album_logos/no-image.jpeg')
    t_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=63)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-release_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    favorites = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    song_file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='song_files', default='song_files/mektub.mp3')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see from these models many users can favorite many songs. In template, I want to add class to songs which are favorited by authenticated user:

```
template
<span {% if authenticated user favorited this song %}class="favorited" {% endif %}></span>
```

My problem is, I don't know how to write "if authenticated user favorited this song" in template. In terminal, I can get this information by this code:

```
user_favorited_this = song.favorite_set.filter(user=sample_user) and True or False
```

I couldn't do the same thing in template, since it doesn't support passing argument to filter method. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: No, You can not apply a filter in the template. You can send two lists from view one for favourite and another for non-favourite. OR you can add a flag in object for marking it favourite or non-favourite.

Comment: Note though that `and True or False` is completely unnecessary. A better pattern would be `song.favorite_set.filter(...).exists()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right. Filter method returns empty queryset when it can't find any match to filters (and True or False would be meaningful if filter returns False when nothing is found). But that is not an answer to my question. My problem is that I can't apply filter method in template and don't know alternative solution.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't just perform the `filter` in the view, and then pass the answer to the template - as a simple boolean flag?

Comment: @WillKeeling how? Can you write exact code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag filter can do what you want:
If the `User.favorite_set.all` has something in common with `Song.favorite_set.all` this means the current user has favorited that song

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

# Method 1 for django queryset (Better)
@register.filter    
def intersection(queryset1,queryset2):
    return queryset1 & queryset2

# Method 2 for queryset or python List
@register.filter
def intersection(queryset1,queryset2):
    return list(set.intersection(set(queryset1),set(queryset2)))
```

html:

```
{% if request.user.favorite_set.all|intersection:song.favorite_set.all %} class="favorited" {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution, but it seems that this method affects page load performance. Now, my songs page is loading slower than before.

Comment: the first one is faster than the 2nd. If you have a lot of data, this would work, but slower. Maybe there could be other ways more powerful to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be simpler to do this in the view, and then pass the result to the template as a boolean flag.

For example:

```
def song_view(request):
    ...
    song = Song.objects.get(pk=request.GET['song_id'])
    is_favorite = song.favorite_set.filter(user=request.user).exists()
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'is_favorite': is_favorite})
```

or for a generic class based view:

```
class SongDetail(DetailView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        song = self.get_object()
        is_favorite = song.favorite_set.filter(user=self.request.user).exists()
        context['is_favorite'] = is_favorite
        return context
```

and then the code in your template can be simplified to:

```
<span {% if is_favorite %}class="favorited" {% endif %}></span>
```

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I don't need to filter songs by one sample user. What I want is to know which songs are favorited by user who visits website (request.user).

Comment: @ElginCahangirov I have updated the answer using the `request.user`.

Comment: how you define 'song' in your answers?